# Can I create one project with Application(GUI) and Windows Service and have one setup which installs both?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating one service which will connect to DB and get some info process it and produce a simple csv file. On the other hand I am also creating an App to insert the data in the DB which eventually service will be using. Do I need to create two separate projects and two separate setup files, or can I have both service and app in one project and just one setup file which will install both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest at least four projects in total:

1. A Class Library project for the common functionality, e.g. data access.
2. A Windows Forms Application project or the like for the GUI.  This project will reference the Class Library project.
3. A Windows Service project.  This project will also reference the Class Library project.
4. A Setup project to install both the GUI app and the Windows Service.

You may find that two separate installers would be more appropriate but it would be possible to use one for both.